# How to remember true/false state of adviser in cookies in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, yii

I have a problem with the following jQuery code. This code is a part of a bigger Yii project. I want this adviser to be visible when I enter site, then when it is closed to save the state in cookies. Then I reload page and it is closed. How can I do this with this code?

```
var adviserIsVisible = true, 
    adviserCookie = getCookie("adviser"),

    if(adviserCookie != "") {
        adviserIsVisible = adviserCookie;
    }

    if(adviserIsVisible == true){
        $("#adviser-slide-button").html("&lt");                 
        $(".adviser-slide").animate({"left": "0px"});
        adviserIsVisible = false;
    }
    else {
        $("#adviser-slide-button").html("&gt"); 
        $(".adviser-slide").animate({"left": "-206px"});
        adviserIsVisible = true;
    }

    $("#adviser-slide-button").live("click",function(){
        if(adviserIsVisible == true){
            $("#adviser-slide-button").html("&lt");
            $(".adviser-slide").animate({"left": "0px"});
            adviserIsVisible = false;
        }
        else{       
            $("#adviser-slide-button").html("&gt");
            $(".adviser-slide").animate({"left": "-206px"});
            adviserIsVisible = true;
        }

    setCookie("adviser", adviserIsVisible, 1);


    });
```

Comment: It would be helpful to explain what currently happens with your code, and where you are having problems.

Comment: Could you provide me with a fiddle, with the adviser slide? so I can give you a better example in my answer

Comment: If you check my answer, I've created an example which shows you how to do the slider. I've got it working by using `margin-left` instead of `left` in the `.animate({});`

Answer (score 0):

The way I go about setting and retrieving cookies is by the two functions i've created as following:

```
function SetTheCookie(key, value)
{
    // Expire date for cookie
    var expires = new Date();
    // Set expire date for cookie
    expires.setTime(expires.getTime() + (1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    // Set cookie key and value which is passed in by parameters 
    document.cookie = key + '=' + value + ';expires=' + expires.toUTCString();
}

function GetTheCookie(key)
{
    // Check to see if there is a cookie matching the value passed in by parameter
    var keyValue = document.cookie.match('(^|;) ?' + key + '=([^;]*)(;|$)');
    return keyValue ? keyValue[2] : null;
}
```

**Example of using the `SetTheCookie` and `GetTheCookie`:**

[EXAMPLE JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/52t5fvgk/2/)