# Use Client IP as cookie, to identify repeated visit and display a message after 1st visit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies

First off, Thanks in advance to anyone who resolves/helps to resolve this problem. And sorry if this is a duplicate(I couldn't find it anywhere, so posted a new question).

So the main issue is I want my webpage to display an alert message, subsequently from when a user visits the page for 2nd time onwards, so I thought IP logging using cookies would be the most unique thing to do, please do suggest if there's a better thing to use.

Browsing till now, did not get me a way to log IP in cookies. Also, the solutions I found were somewhat similar but they were in PHP, which, I'm not good at.

I would prefer using JavaScript as opposed to jQuery, but all and any help is appreciated.

Comment: I do not understand why you are mentioning an IP address here. A cookie is fine, store whatever information you require in there. The IP address is nothing you are interested in. It typically changes with time because of dynamic usage and many clients can share the same address in case if NAT. So the IP address typically is not of any use for a server or application. A cookie serves your need well: if it exists the client has visited before.

Comment: You can also use `local storage`..better to handle than `cookies`.

Comment: Using the IP address isn't the best way of doing this because there could be many machines behind NAT routers sharing one IP. Also many mobile networks change IP address on each access.

Comment: Onload check if a cookie is set, if yes > send a message and if no > set the cookie. You don't need to bind it to a ip as it is already bound to that device

Comment: Why don't you use a server side session, that way you would have a session which is unique to that person visiting the website?                           

But if you was going to use cookie, I wouldn't use the `IP`because the `IP` address changes on mobile because you'll be connecting to different networks. Also you could have multiple connections on the same router `IP` address. So I wouldn't recommend using the `IP`.

Comment: Also I would have this check on the client side (javascript/JQuery) because people can turn of JavaScript. So if you was going to be making a user session for example, they could turn of the javascript. So I would recommend making it more secure with PHP (server side). This is only if you was making user accounts for your website. (I don't know if you're doing this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off before I give different ways of identify repeated visit and display a message after 1st visit.

I would recommend not using the IP address because there could be multiple machines behind the NAT routers sharing the one IP address, there will also be a the problem of mobiles always changing their IP address because they will also be connecting to different networks.

There is multiple ways of doing this:

I would recommend using either **Option 3** or **Option 4** so that there is nothing stored on the users machine. It is then much more secure that client side because people can store of JavaScript on their browsers.

**Option 1:**

You could have a client side local storage by using the HTML5 Web Storage.

[HTML5 Web Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

> Before HTML5, application data had to be stored in cookies, included in every server request. Local storage is more secure, and large amounts of data can be stored locally, without affecting website performance.
>
> Unlike cookies, the storage limit is far larger (at least 5MB) and
> information is never transferred to the server.
>
> Local storage is per origin (per domain and protocol). All pages, from
> one origin, can store and access the same data.

**Option 2:**

You could go with using a client side cookie, which you would set and remove with JavaScript:

> Cookies are data, stored in small text files, on your computer.
>
> When a web server has sent a web page to a browser, the connection is
> shut down, and the server forgets everything about the user.
>
> Cookies were invented to solve the problem "how to remember
> information about the user":
>
> When a user visits a web page, his name can be stored in a cookie.
> Next time the user visits the page, the cookie "remembers" his name.
> Cookies are saved in name-value pairs like:
>
> `username=John`

I've actually done an example of this few days ago.

[COOKIE EXAMPLE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32741593/3296661)

**Option 3:**

You could have a session, which is a good way of checking if you are having users logging into your website/application:

[PHP Sessions](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

> A session is a way to store information (in variables) to be used across multiple pages.
>
> Unlike a cookie, the information is not stored on the users computer.
>
> When you work with an application, you open it, do some changes, and
> then you close it. This is much like a Session. The computer knows who
> you are. It knows when you start the application and when you end. But
> on the internet there is one problem: the web server does not know who
> you are or what you do, because the HTTP address doesn't maintain
> state.
>
> Session variables solve this problem by storing user information to be
> used across multiple pages (e.g. username, favorite color, etc). By
> default, session variables last until the user closes the browser.
>
> So; Session variables hold information about one single user, and are
> available to all pages in one application.

**Option 4:**

You could use server side cookies (this way it's not stored on users machine), this is a good way of identifying a user (visitor):

[PHP Cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp)

> A cookie is often used to identify a user.
>
> A cookie is often used to identify a user. A cookie is a small file
> that the server embeds on the user's computer. Each time the same
> computer requests a page with a browser, it will send the cookie too.
> With PHP, you can both create and retrieve cookie values.