# Cookie from JS vs Cookie in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies

I do something like this:

JS:

```
Cookies.set(post_id + '_' + user_ip, post_id + "_" + user_ip, { expires: 1 });
```

PHP:

```
$cookie_str = $post_id.'_'.get_client_ip();
if (isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_str_]) ){
    print_r('ok exist');
}
```

But it doesn't work ... cookie exist I check in network in chrome developer tools. Is there some different between cookies in JS and PHP ? or I do some stupid mistake? IP is always that same ... console.log() form JS shows that same IP like PHP

**ANSWER:**

Ok I remove IP from cookie name and value and it start working:
Cookie like : 54_23.23.211.2 was not visible by $_COOKIE[ ];

Now cookie is only a simple number of $post_id;

But why "54_23.23.211.2" doesn't work, I don't know... cookie like cookie = dots are not permitted ?

YES - http://harrybailey.com/2009/04/dots-arent-allowed-in-php-cookie-names/

**Dots are not permitted in PHP cookies** :)

Comment: Storing user's IP as a part of cookie's key sounds wrong for me...

Comment: Why? It's just simple on('click') event ... when user click and download I set cookie and hide button ... of course he can delete cookies and download second time but I see no sense set more security ... and Your comment is off-topic ;)

Comment: So, why don't use just use `post_id`? Isn't it enough? What is the purpose of IP within a cookie name?

Comment: And what give me post_id for non logged user?

Comment: And what does IP give to you for non-logged user? Cookie is a user-side container. If a user has this cookie - it means that he already has clicked your button whatever his IP is. If he does not have this cookie - it hasn't clicked or removed it, whatever his IP is now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript cookies vs php cookies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562325/javascript-cookies-vs-php-cookies)

Comment: What gives me? That even when he reload page he won't be able to download second time for X time that same file ...

Comment: No it's not duplicate ... I don't understand peopls like You ... You won't help but looking for problems.

Comment: Please do not put the answer in the question - _write an answer_ and accept it; You've asked a lot of questions to seemingly not know how SO works.... Also note that someone flagging a question as a _possible_ duplicate is not a personal attack against you.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion i would go with using the `post_id` instead of `post_id` and `user_ip`

I recommend not using the IP address because there could be multiple machines behind the NAT routers sharing the one IP address, there will also be a the problem of mobiles always changing their IP address because they will also be connecting to different networks.

Please check this post I did for someone: **https://stackoverflow.com/a/32758176/3296661**

However if you want to stick with the method you've got try this:

Use `str_replace()` to strip all the dots from the IP address on PHP side and use `split('.').join("")` on JS side. This way both client and server side will match.

This is because dots are not permitted in PHP cookies.

JS:

```
user_ip = post_id.split('.').join("");
Cookies.set(post_id + '_' + user_ip, post_id + "_" + user_ip, { expires: 1 });
```

**PHP:**

```
$cookie_str = $post_id . str_replace(".","", get_client_ip());

if (isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_str_]) )
{
    print_r('ok exist');
}
```

Comment: But user do not need to register to download ... how in other way prevent multiple downloads by that same non logged user ... only IP I think

Comment: @Michael - So why don't you just make a random ID for when the user enters page, then store that in cookie? So that the non registered user has a ID?

Comment: And this ID will be based on ? What if he reload page ? Give him new ID ?

Comment: @Michael - If he refreshes page, you just check if there is already a cookie. If there is then don't give them new ID.

Comment: hm ok I do not need IPs just post_id and check if cookie exist ... but it's all time off-topic ... PHP do not see cookie from JS

Comment: @Michael Just use PHP cookie and include the php script at top of page, and just check the php cookie without JS?

Comment: I can't - I must check on('click') it's just simples download ... But ok, without IP it works ... I don't know why but only numer "54" in cookie and it works - "54_123.234.23.1" - this doesn't.

Comment: Thanks but I edited my question - dots are not permitted in PHP cookies - that's why PHP doesn't see cookie at all. "_" are permitted soo your edit doesn't change anything.

Comment: ok it might work ... but somehow I missed that enough is to check whether the cookie with X name exists because it is work on the client side and not server side :)) but bug was in cookies dots JS save it but $_COOKIE doesn't see it.

Comment: You can strip it of all dots on client side and php side. So it matches on both sides.

Comment: Yes I can ... thanks for Your time ... testing ,testing,testing ;-)

Comment: @Michael - Well hopefully you can use this method to start using the IP address again :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the source code of your `Cookie` object but `expires: 1` looks like your cookie is set to expire one second later.

Comment: No it's 1 day like plugin doc say. It's jquery-cookie plugin.